# When using threading in python within a csv each thread runs a different line of the csv but everything else the same/

Tags: python, multithreading, csv

Fairly new to Python (and coding as it is!)

Running a programme which parses a CSV, and will then run a function using data from that CSV.

```
def Name_check():
            if row['Name'] == "x":
                Function()
            else:
                print("Not available at this time")


def Function():
    with open("tasks.csv", 'r+') as file:
        product_link = row['Link']



with open("tasks.csv", 'r+') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        threading.Thread(target=Name_check).start()
```

The CSV is formatted:

Name, Link

--,--

--,--

`Function()` is a function which will do a GET request and scrape the HTML based on the `product_link` and `print()` certain sections of the HTML.

Above is a section of my code so far, however, when I run this it will only run `Function()`  for the last line in the CSV with Name = x, it does not matter if this is the first row or the last row. However, I want it to run the function for all lines of the CSV with Name = x. So if row 1 has Name 'x' and link www.example.org and row 2 also has name 'x' and link www.example2.org, there will be one GET request at www.example.org and another at www.example2.org.

These GET requests to need to happen at roughly the same time, so it can't be `Name_check()` for row 1, `Function()` for row 1 then `Name_check()` for row 2 then `Function()` for row 2.

I'm sure this is quite an easy fix but any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `row` is in the global namespace but should be passed as a local parameter.  By the time the thread runs your files has probably read all the rows and `row` equals the last line.  Reading the file again in `Function` doesn't make sense and `file` isn't used.  Also, if you had 1000 tasks and 5 "Name=x" lines, you'd currently create 1000 threads.  Something like this should work:

```
import threading
import csv

def Function(product_link):
    print(product_link)

with open('tasks.csv',newline='') as file:  # newline='' per csv documentation.
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        if row['Name'] == 'x':  # Just create a thread when needed.
            # Pass the link to process
            threading.Thread(target=Function,args=(row['Link'],)).start()
```